# What is the purpose of supports property in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working with a legacy code and I am wondering what is the support property that is being used in most of the components. I haven't seen it yet in documentation, and can't find any info about it.
This is how the components look like with that property:

```
const Panel = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(injectIntl(handlingForm({
  form: formName,
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(PanelImpl)));

Panel.supports = (bp, apCodes) => bp === handlingCodes.PANEL|| actionPoints.some(ap => apCodes.includes(ap));
```

I have found that it is being used to check whether to render the component or not:

```
 {Panel.supports(bp, apCodes)
  && (
    <Panel
      submitCallback={submitCallback}
      readOnly={readOnly}
      readOnlySubmitButton={readOnlySubmitButton}
      apCodes={apCodes}
    />
  )
  }
```

So, I guess what I am wondering is, what is being returned from `connect` function, and does `support` property exists in the returned object or we can add any property to it, like supports is added here?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: That looks like a very project specific thing. Keep in mind that you can arbitrarily add new properties on any JavaScript object and technically functions are objects.